# jquery ui autocomplete is returning only one value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am having trouble on my autocomplete as it is returning only one record whereas the remote webservice is returning 10 items.

Was wondering if you could have a look at my code and see if I'm doing something wrong?

Received data:

> {"d":"[\"02102008633\",\"02102008794\",\"02102008980\",\"02102015321\",\"02102018743\",\"02102024602\",\"02102037454\",\"02102038366\",\"02102040774\",\"02102056369\"]"}

```
jQuery(txtDestination).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/SearchService.asmx/GetDestinationAutocompleteValue?" + "accountCode=" + accountCode.toString() + "&criteria=" + jQuery(txtDestination).val().toString(),
                    data: "{}",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != null && data.hasOwnProperty('d') && eval(data.d) != null) {
                            var result = new Array(eval(data.d));
                            response(jQuery.map(result, function (item, ctr) {
                                return { label: item[ctr], id: item[ctr], value: item[ctr] }
                            }));
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown); }
                });
            }
        });
```

Thanks a million!

Cheers,
Ann

Comment: what does the result of JQuery.map look like?

Comment: in addition to Xavier's correct-looking answer, please reread the "Overview" section of http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ specifically, you should **always** call `response()` (you don't do so in your error handling), you should (if possible) return valid json object data from the server, so you're not forced to `eval()` like that

Comment: Thanks for the tip @davin! Will try to review this again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it...  Take a look at this line:

```
var result = new Array(eval(data.d));
```

Now, since `eval(data.d)` evaluates to an array already, you're essentially calling something like this:

```
var result = new Array([1, 2, 3]);
```

Which will actually create an array of length one - the first element of which is an array of length three.  This blindsided me, too, until I thought to check it in a JS console (and don't get me started on the printout not including square brackets...):

```
js> ra1 = new Array(1, 2, 3)
1,2,3
js> ra2 = new Array([1, 2, 3])
1,2,3
js> ra1.length
3
js> ra2.length
1
```

But the good news is that there's an easy fix:

```
var result = eval(data.d);
```

Hope this helps!